# Programming alternatives to referencing DLLs or projects in a solution

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, dll, reference, wrapper

I could not think of a proper title to this question. But here is my dilemma:

I have a solution which has more than 5 projects. I am concerned with 3 of those projects, let's call them project **A**, project **B** and project **C**. Project **A is referenced in B** and **B is referenced in C**.  (That is, B refers to A and C refers to B)

I need to call a function in project C which belongs to a class in A.

My problem is that I cannot refer project A in C as it would break the build. I tried to create an object of a class which belongs to B and call the function through that object. But this raised an error which required a reference to A.

Is there a way to call that function without including the reference?

A colleague of mine suggested to create a wrapper class in B which calls the function in A as a workaround. But I doubt it would help as creating the object of the wrapper class in C will raise a requirement of a reference to A again.

Comment: "My problem is that I cannot refer project A in C as it would break the build." Why? A reference from C to A should be fine, given that C refers to B and B refers to A. If you meant the other way round (causing a cycle) that would be a different matter.

Comment: @JonSkeet There are other projects in the solution. There are some dependencies which will lead to this.

Comment: @aman if there are other dependencies that cause a collision or a reference cycle, you need to include them in the question so that we can provide a comprehensive answer :)

Comment: @zaitsman My visibility is limited to these three projects only, which is why I framed the question like this :)

Comment: @aman then i'm afraid the question as it is posted is meaningless as the conditions you specified would NOT cause a reference cycle as indicated by Jon Skeet.

Comment: In particular, C clearly already has an *indirect* dependency on A... so why can't you make that direct?

Comment: @JonSkeet Your point is very valid, but I am helpless here. Any reference to A from C will lead to a breakage and this is due to existing design flaws and project implementations (which are out of my control). But is there a way here in which we can bypass the reference using code only? (any other alternative is also welcome :) )

Comment: Then you should *explain that in the question*. Chances are the reasons for that breakage (which still sounds hard to believe) could impact other options too.

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround you can do this through reflection:

```
Assembly asm = Assembly.LoadFile(@"pathToDllHere\ProjectA.dll");

Type t = asm.GetType("ProjectA.ClassName");

MethodInfo methodInfo = t.GetMethod("MyMethod", new Type[] { typeof(string), typeof(int) });

Object o = Activator.CreateInstance(t);

object[] parameters = new object[2]
{
    "sample parameter", 1337
};

var result = methodInfo.Invoke(o, parameters);

Console.WriteLine(result);
```

Where the ProjectA.ClassName looks like:

```
public class ClassName
{
    public string MyMethod(string a, int b)
    {
        return "called from A";
    }
}
```

Comment: `Assembly asn = Assembly.LoadFile(...)`

Are you using this to make a dynamic reference to Project A?